imagick extension not working in Ubuntu php8.2-fpm, nginx server
I have installed imagemagick extension in my VPS server. It's fully working with the php cli.
Running php -i it shows that the extension is successfully enabled, however, in the php82-fpm the extension is not loaded.
I am checking this echoing phpmyinfo() and it does not show the extension also, other functions dependent on the extension is not loading through nginx server, but working through command line php interface.
